# Ubuntu 13.04 - installation Nvidia driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, apt, xorg, 13.04

I've installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my laptop HP 6720s with video card Intel 965 chipset Intel gma x3100. After the boot the classic purple screen appear and before the login page the screen become black and the pc remain freezed.

For all last versions of Ubuntu the following commands repaired the situation:

**Recovery mode with network:**

```
apt-get remove --purge nvidia*
rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
apt-get update
apt-get
```

**Recovery mode again:**

```
apt-get install nvidia-current
nvidia-xconfig
reboot
```

But for the 13.04 version it doesn't work.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: @zendessert This option you described here is all greyed out for Additional Drivers and says "No proprietary drivers are in use."

Answer (score 5):

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to reach the first virtual console. Log in there, then follow the instructions.

To get all the relevant stuff, including the kernel sources and kernel headers run next command

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-source linux-headers
```

If the package `linux-headers` is not available, try running the command by specifying the exact version of the headers with:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

Next, install the current Nvidia driver:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

Once the installation completes successfully, check if the Nvidia driver is loaded:

```
sudo /sbin/lsmod | grep nvidia
```

If it's not, you will need to manually insert into memory. First, make sure all kernel module dependencies are satisfied and resolved:

```
sudo depmod -a
```

Then, load the driver:

```
sudo modprobe nvidia_current
```

This should succeed and the `lsmod` command should show it's loaded, but the usage count will probably be 0, because nothing will be using it yet. You will need to restart the graphics environment to actually benefit from the driver:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm restart
```

This will restart the graphics environment, you will see the Nvidia splash, and you will load into a desktop that has the Nvidia driver running, and all that. Your problem is now resolved.

[image]
[image]

Source: http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/ubuntu-quetzal-nvidia.html (even if the specified source is related to Ubuntu 12.10, I test this method and is working perfectly on Ubuntu 13.04).

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your time! It works until the command sudo modprobe nvidia_current
And it says: FATAL: Module nvidia_current not found. The following command lightdm restart feezes the pc. A restart of the laptop provide again a black screen.

Comment: Do this in tty1 (first virtual console), Ctrl + Alt + F1

Comment: Yes, I'm in tty1 mode, try to reinstall from cd. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Solved only after a fresh install. Thank you a lot.

Comment: This just ripped me a new one. I did it in the gui like an idiot and now I can't get my desktop back. I can open windows with hotkeys, but other than that she's cashed.

Comment: Same effing error "FATAL: Module nvidia_current" not found... in 13.04.  Do I really have to reinstall?  This is a FRESH install as is... nothing has been installed.

Comment: @JoshuaRountree Have you tried all of these from tty1?

Comment: I'm sorry, is that what appears after you hit CTRL+ALT+F1?

Comment: @JoshuaRountree Yep...

Comment: Then yes, that's the only place I tried it...

Comment: Tried this now, http://www.howopensource.com/2012/10/install-nvidia-geforce-driver-in-ubuntu-12-10-12-04-using-ppa/ and same issue :-/ Assuming my graphics card is bad?

Comment: Did the restart on lightdm and I get the plain desktop with no left bar or top bar.

Comment: Also, when I type sudo modprobe nvidia_304 it says `ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia_304': No such device`

Comment: FYI I'm running 8600 GT?

Comment: Relating to the new problem with plain desktop see http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears

Comment: @JoshuaRountree Also see this post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers/61433#61433

Answer (score 3):

It is easier to follow this approach:

1. Click the gear icon in the top right corner of the screen.
2. Click "System settings..."
3. Click "Software & Updates" in the "System" category.
4. Click on the "Additional Drivers" tab and select the proprietary driver.
5. Click "Apply Changes".

Reboot, job done!