# Stuck in some kind of test pattern loop after installing NVidia Drivers

Tags: nvidia, 13.04, xorg

I just installed the latest Ubuntu and then enabled the restricted drivers for NVIDIA
Once I rebooted, the system starts but then enters some kind of graphical test pattern loop
 (Blue, Black, White, Grey, and finally all colours in horizontal bars)

At this point the system does not respond to any key combinations or mouse input.
Rebooting the system multiple times does not help either.

**Update:**

Just found this post: [Ubuntu 13.04 - installation Nvidia driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291199/help-13-04-installation-nvidia-driver?rq=1)

The difference being that I cannot even get into a terminal with `CTRL`+`ALT`+`F1`

**Update 2:**

By booting in recovery mode in a root shell I was able to remove the driver
and then follow the instructions from the other post. Same coloured screens as a result.

Comment: Try `CTRL`+`ALT`+`T`

Comment: What about recovery mode?

Comment: Tried that, will update the question

Answer (score 0):

I seems to me that the display driver has been set (probably by its self!) to the wrong resolution.

On your next reboot, at the Start up options, 
[image]
move the mouse cursor down to the Ubuntu Advanced options section of the menu. Click on the second
At the Next Screen, choose the following option:
[image]
And finally on the third screen click on the following option:
[image]
This should allow you to boot up and adjust your screen resolution.

Hope this helps

Comment: let me give that a try

Comment: Actually.. what menu? All I get is grub

Comment: Also... I can't see any of the images you posted

Comment: Ok, using a VPN I was able to view the images, not it makes sense.

Comment: But anyway, even using FaleSafeX mode, I still get the test pattern. It's a pretty standard computer, an HP TouchSmart600.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying, Just had to reinstall everything as I was fiddling with the network and killed it. I am quite new to Ubuntu, and I can not think of anything else at present, but will keep looking.

Comment: Did you manage to run Ubuntu in low graphics mode?

Comment: No, the exact same problem...

Comment: I just installed Ubuntu on another system with a different NVIDIA GPU and now I just get a black screen... I'm not sure the issue is caused by Ubuntu or NVIDIA but it does seem like a showstopper given that they want to position Ubuntu as a desktop OS for end users instead of the other two important desktop operating systems out there...