# Can't Install nvidia driver on ubuntu 13.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, overheating

Here's the case.

My Computer can boot ubuntu 13.04 but the time it loads my unity session --I have set autologin, the video card chrashes and the monitor blacks out.

Even if I go console to do the job, because of the autologin, it again chrases.

Then I decided to go to the single login by adding `single` on the kernel parameter on grub at boot. It again crashes. But when I try to boot to windows, everything works out just fine.

Ps: I have also tried to use `nomodeset` on the kernel parameter. I have also guessing that the gpu HAD overheated because when I touched the gpu it is really hot. I have nvidia geforce GT220. I have also done this at dawn.

Comment: What errors are displayed (if any)?

Comment: There's none, when the video card crashes the computer will too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for an answer I figure out that It has a particular time usually 3mins before it crashes. I've managed to add `text` to the kernel parameter then login and run the nvidia*.run as root and quickly choose yes to all. Then I quickly typed `sudo lightdm` then it never crashes since the next reboot

Answer (score 0):

Same question [nvidia install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291199/ubuntu-13-04-installation-nvidia-driver)

You can also get helps from here: [Install nvidia](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/ubuntu-ringtail-nvidia.html)