# Ubuntu 13.10 + Nvidia 173 (Dell Precision M60) - black screen, cannot boot

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 13.10, xorg, dell

I upgraded a Dell Precision M60 which uses a NVIDIA GPU Quadro FX Go1000 (NV36GL) graphics card from Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10 today and now I cannot boot. Starting X flashes an NVIDIA logo briefly and then brings up a black screen and the keyboard is unresponsive - even CTRL + ALT + F1 to bring up a terminal login / window does not work.

I am using the nvidia-173 drivers (173.14.37-0ubuntu4) - nvidia-current does NOT work on this graphics card as it is not supported. An earlier driver present on 13.04, nvidia-173-updates, no longer appears to exist. I have followed instructions in other threads such as [Ubuntu 13.04 - installation Nvidia driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291199/ubuntu-13-04-installation-nvidia-driver) and completely uninstalled all nvidia drivers and X, and reinstalled it. Same problem. I haven't followed instructions to install nvidia-current as I know this brings up a "not supported - use nvidia-173" message as follows

```
[   44.659 (WW) NVIDIA(0): The NVIDIA Quadro FX Go1000 GPU installed in this system is
[   44.659 (WW) NVIDIA(0):     supported through the NVIDIA 173.14.xx Legacy drivers.
[   44.659 (WW) NVIDIA(0):     Please visit http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html for
[   44.659 (WW) NVIDIA(0):     more information.   The 304.88 NVIDIA driver will ignore
[   44.659 (WW) NVIDIA(0):     this GPU. Continuing probe....
```

The only way to recover is to boot into recovery mode and drop into a root shell prompt. I can access the laptop via ssh once X is loaded to do diagnostics. Running X remotely gets as far as running the NV_CONTROL module, then gives up

If I remove all nvidia drivers completely using apt-get remove --purge nvidia*, X picks up the VESA driver and boots into 640x480.

I don't have an xorg.conf present and the relevant bit of the most recent Xorg.0.log is as follows

```
[    50.717] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    50.717] (II) Loading /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/libglx.so
[    51.064] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    51.064]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    51.064]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    51.064] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  173.14.37  Wed Mar  6 17:14:50 PST 2013
[    51.064] Loading extension GLX
[    51.064] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 0
[    51.064] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 1
[    51.064] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 2
[    51.064] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 3
[    51.064] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 4
[    51.064] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    51.064] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    51.064] (II) Loading /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so
[    51.065] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    51.065]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    51.065]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    51.065] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[    51.066] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[    51.095] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    51.095]    compiled for 1.14.2.901, module version = 1.0.9
[    51.095]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    51.095]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 14.1
[    51.095] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    51.096] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    51.096] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    51.096]    compiled for 1.14.1, module version = 2.3.2
[    51.096]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    51.096]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 14.1
[    51.096] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    51.096] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    51.114] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    51.114]    compiled for 1.14.1, module version = 0.8.0
[    51.115]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    51.115]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 14.1
[    51.115] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    51.115] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    51.117] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    51.117]    compiled for 1.14.1, module version = 0.4.3
[    51.117]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    51.117]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 14.1
[    51.117] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  173.14.37  Wed Mar  6 17:02:37 PST 2013
[    51.117] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[    51.117] (II) NOUVEAU driver Date:   Wed Jul 31 10:51:03 2013 +1000
[    51.117] (II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :
[    51.117]    RIVA TNT        (NV04)
[    51.117]    RIVA TNT2       (NV05)
[    51.117]    GeForce 256     (NV10)
[    51.117]    GeForce 2       (NV11, NV15)
[    51.117]    GeForce 4MX     (NV17, NV18)
[    51.117]    GeForce 3       (NV20)
[    51.118]    GeForce 4Ti     (NV25, NV28)
[    51.118]    GeForce FX      (NV3x)
[    51.118]    GeForce 6       (NV4x)
[    51.118]    GeForce 7       (G7x)
[    51.118]    GeForce 8       (G8x)
[    51.118]    GeForce GTX 200 (NVA0)
[    51.118]    GeForce GTX 400 (NVC0)
[    51.118] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[    51.118] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[    51.118] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    51.118] (++) using VT number 7
[    51.120] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[    51.120] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[    51.120] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[    51.120] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    51.120]    compiled for 1.14.3, module version = 1.0.0
[    51.120]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    51.120] (II) Loading sub module "wfb"
[    51.120] (II) LoadModule: "wfb"
[    51.120] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[    51.121] (II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    51.121]    compiled for 1.14.3, module version = 1.0.0
[    51.121]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    51.121] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[    51.121] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[    51.121] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[    51.121] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[    51.121] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[    51.121] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[    51.121] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[    51.121] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    51.121] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    51.121] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    51.135] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    51.136]    compiled for 1.14.3, module version = 0.0.2
[    51.136]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 14.1
[    51.136] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
[    51.136] (II) NVIDIA(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[    51.136] (==) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[    51.136] (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
[    51.136] (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    51.136] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[    51.136] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling RENDER acceleration
[    51.136] (II) NVIDIA(0): Support for GLX with the Damage and Composite X extensions is
[    51.136] (II) NVIDIA(0):     enabled.
[    52.407] (II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU Quadro FX Go1000 (NV36GL) at PCI:1:0:0 (GPU-0)
[    52.407] (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 131072 kBytes
[    52.407] (--) NVIDIA(0): VideoBIOS: 04.36.20.30.d1
[    52.407] (II) NVIDIA(0): Detected AGP rate: 4X
[    52.407] (--) NVIDIA(0): Interlaced video modes are supported on this GPU
[    52.407] (--) NVIDIA(0): Connected display device(s) on Quadro FX Go1000 at PCI:1:0:0:
[    52.407] (--) NVIDIA(0):     Sharp (DFP-0)
[    52.407] (--) NVIDIA(0): Sharp (DFP-0): 300.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    52.407] (--) NVIDIA(0): Sharp (DFP-0): Internal Dual Link LVDS
[    52.408] (II) NVIDIA(0): Assigned Display Device: DFP-0
[    52.408] (==) NVIDIA(0): 
[    52.408] (==) NVIDIA(0): No modes were requested; the default mode "nvidia-auto-select"
[    52.408] (==) NVIDIA(0):     will be used as the requested mode.
[    52.408] (==) NVIDIA(0): 
[    52.408] (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated modes:
[    52.408] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "nvidia-auto-select"
[    52.408] (II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 1920 x 1200
[    52.408] (--) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (147, 145); computed from "UseEdidDpi" X config
[    52.408] (--) NVIDIA(0):     option
[    52.408] (WW) NVIDIA(0): UBB is incompatible with the Composite extension.  Disabling
[    52.408] (WW) NVIDIA(0):     UBB.
[    52.408] (==) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 32-bit ARGB GLX visuals.
[    52.408] (II) UnloadModule: "nouveau"
[    52.408] (II) Unloading nouveau
[    52.409] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[    52.409] (II) Unloading vesa
[    52.409] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[    52.409] (II) Unloading modesetting
[    52.409] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[    52.409] (II) Unloading fbdev
[    52.409] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[    52.409] (II) Unloading fbdevhw
[    52.409] (--) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[    52.412] (II) NVIDIA(0): Initialized AGP GART.
[    52.415] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Failed to determine power source of the system : Unable to
[    52.415] (WW) NVIDIA(0):     find AC state file under /proc/acpi/ac_adapter/
[    52.416] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "nvidia-auto-select"
[    52.653] Loading extension NV-GLX
[    52.705] (II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA 3D Acceleration Architecture Initialized
[    52.708] (II) NVIDIA(0): Using the NVIDIA 2D acceleration architecture
[    52.708] (==) NVIDIA(0): Backing store disabled
[    52.708] (==) NVIDIA(0): Silken mouse enabled
[    52.708] (==) NVIDIA(0): DPMS enabled
[    52.708] Loading extension NV-CONTROL
[    52.708] (==) RandR enabled
[    52.720] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[    52.721] (II) Initializing extension GLX
```

Comment: Additional - when I boot up and it locks on the nvidia splash screen, I can ssh in and using top I find that apport is stuck on nearly 100% CPU

Comment: After hours of banging my head, I have fixed the problem. I ran apt-get remove --purge nvidia-173, then downloaded the latest drivers (173.14.39) from NVidia's website. The desktop then booted up as expected. The current Ubuntu nvidia-173 package still uses an earlier version of the driver (173.14.37), so it looks like somebody needs to rebuild and update that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(As per the OP's own answer in a comment:)

1. Check on Nvidia's [Unix Driver Archive](http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html) or [Driver Downloads](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us) which version of their drivers support your card (`Quadro FX 1000`). In this case it's `173.14.39`.
2. Check on [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) if this package is provided for `13.10`. If not (as is the case here), then check for it in the `proposed` repo (see [how to search for proposed updates on ubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/400944/how-to-search-for-proposed-updates-on-ubuntu-com) and [BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia)). Unfortunately it seems that `173.14.39` isn't packaged for `Saucy` even in `proposed`: ["nvidia-graphics-drivers-173" package in Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-173).
3. If it were available in `proposed`, you'd have needed to enable it in `Synaptic > Settings > Repos > Updates > Proposed` and then install it. But since this is (currently) not an option, you can `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-173`, then download the latest drivers (`173.14.39`) from Nvidia's website and install that.